# Number of Support vectors in SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, vector, svm

How do I print the number of support vectors for a particular SVM model?
Please suggest a code snippet in Python.

```py
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

x, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_informative=5,
                           n_redundant=5, n_classes=3, random_state=1)
model = SVC()
ovr = OneVsRestClassifier(model)
ovr.fit(x, y)
ovr.support_vectors_
```

the last line prints out all the support vectors, but not the number of support vectors.

Comment: How were you able to print support vectors using `ovr.support_vectors_`. I see ['OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'support_vectors_'](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html)

Comment: Can you include the last line output?

Comment: @Pluviophile yeah, that was a mistake on my part - ovr.support_vectors_, shows a bug that I did not notice. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

use `len()`

```py
len(ovr.support_vectors_)
```